# How to set a live event listner on a class to auto resize its height with its contents resize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wonder how to set an event listner on a class such that would auto resize it with its contents resize? By default I have next CSS set on that class:

```
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
```

And I want only its height to change on its contents size change. How to do such thing with jQuery?

Comment: can you tel me more about this? when your object create? why you cant add your CSS when you creating that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [resize event plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function chkResize() {
/*your object which ones are you want to change*/
};
$(window).resize(function () {
    chkResize();
});
```

Put them in your `$(function(){ });`